# Difference between itertools.islice and read function

Tags: python, memory-management, file-handling, python-itertools

I am trying to get a better understanding of how to handle files with millions of records with minimum memory usage.

To practice, I created a file with ~6.5 million lines and wrote a couple of functions to split it into ~7 files with a million lines each. In the first function, I used the python file read method to create the logic such that a new file is created after 1 million  lines are read until we hit the last file where the remaining 500K lines are written.

That function takes FOREVER to run.

Then, I created another function to split the file using itertools.islice. That took a little under ~2 seconds to run.

Now, I know that islice is an iterator that iterates of the file object so its expected to be more memory efficient. However, how is it different than the read() method?

I thought even read() goes through each line in the the file one by one (kind of like an iterator..). So, I was expecting the performance of the two programs to be similar . Can you guys help me understand why islice is SO MUCH faster ?

Here are both pieces of code -

## 1 using read() -

```
with open("bigfile.txt","r") as f:
    filenum = 1
    j = 1
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if j <= 1000000:
            with open("big_out_%d" % filenum, "a") as outfile:
                outfile.write(line)
        j += 1
        if j == 1000000:
            j = 1
            filenum += 1
            with open("big_out_%d" % filenum, "a") as outfile:
                outfile.write(line)
```

## 2 using islice -

```
import itertools
import time

start = time.time()

with open("bigfile.txt","r") as f:
    i = 1
    while True:
        chunk = list(itertools.islice(f, 1000000))
        if not chunk:
            print "reached the end"
            break
        with open("out%d.txt" % i, "w") as out:
            out.writelines(chunk)
        print i
        i += 1

end = time.time()
print "time is %d" % ((end-start))
```

Comment: Your first example is missing `read`... Reading 1M lines one by one or at once makes all the difference. Your first does read-write-read-write each line, maximizing IO overhead.

Comment: You're converting the `islice` object to a list immediately, so this code doesn't benefit from the fact that `islice` won't read all the lines at once. It turns out that reading a big chunk of the file at once and then _writing this chunk_ at once is faster than reading and writing line-by-line.

Comment: @ForceBru it helps because it makes lazily reading the first 1M lines possible. Of course one could use a listcomp.

Comment: @AndrasDeak, but the `islice` object is converted to a list immediately, so all 1M lines will be read immediately, not lazily, because lists aren't lazy.

Comment: Lazily compared to `f.read()` or `list(f)`, @ForceBru.

Comment: @ForceBru - The reason I had to convert the islice object to a list was because without doing so my code was getting stuck in an infinite loop. This is what I had -
```
 chunk = itertools.islice(f, 1000000)
        if not chunk:
            print "reached the end"
            break
```
The problem with this code was "if not chunk" never matched since even after all the lines of my file got consumed the islice object existed... Is there another approach to do this? I would love to keep the "generator" logic of islice intact and use it to fetch each line and write it to a file..

Answer (score 3):

The difference has nothing to do with islice versus read(). Your two programs differ greatly in their logic.

In the first listing, you loop over the lines of the file.  In each iteration of the loop, you open the file, write one line, and then close the file again.  (The "with open" syntax causes the file to be closed at the end of the with: block). By the time you are finished, you have written 6500000 lines into seven different files, but you have also performed 6500000 file opens and 6500000 file closings.  I am not surprised that the OS cannot do this efficiently.

In the second listing you read in a chunk of 1000000 lines and then write all of that once.  You still write 6500000 lines but here you perform 7 opens and 7 closes.  Not the same thing at all.

Using with: for the output files makes your first listing very clumsy.  Try this:

```
with open("bigfile.txt","r") as f:
    filenum = 1
    j = 1
    outfile = open("big_out_%d" % filenum, "w")
    try:
        for line in f:
            outfile.write(line)
            j += 1
            if j == 1000000:
                outfile.close()
                j = 1
                filenum += 1
                outfile = open("big_out_%d" % filenum, "w")
    finally:
        outfile.close()
```

I didn't test this code.  If there's a mistake in it, it should be easy to fix.

With this approach you never load more than one line at a time into memory.

Comment: I have a question on this "With this approach you never load more than one line at a time into memory." Since I am writing each line individually to the output file which stores 1 Million entries, the memory is indeed "loading" 1 million lines.No? 

I get that there is clear savings from having to open/close file 7times vs 6.5 M times but is there any benefit of loading each line & writing it to file v/s loading 1M lines using islice in a list & then writing the list to a file.I guess in the latter approach, I hit a point where there are 2M lines in the memory? (1M in the list & the file?)

Comment: By memory I mean "program memory" or maybe you could call it "Python" memory.  In your second program your variable `chunk` is a list containing one million strings, all of which must be alive in program memory at the same time.  Once you assign a new list to the variable `chunk`, Python will reclaim the memory used to store the previous list.  You will, as you say, momentarily have 2 million strings in memory.  But in my program the variable `line` is just one string, so instead of 2 million live objects I have only 2.  Two million isn't a huge number for a modern PC, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The first version of the code opens and closes the output file for every line it writes. That's going to be amazingly slow, as it will flush the buffer to disk every time. Just keeping the file open in between lines is probably the biggest speedup of the second version (though reading and writing many lines in a row may offer modest additional benefits as long as you can hold all the lines in memory at the same time).

You might try a third version of the code, which is part way between your current two versions. It still reads and writes single lines, but keeps the output file open in between writes:

```
with open("bigfile.txt","r") as f:
    outfile = None
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i % 1000000 == 0:
            if outfile:
                outfile.close()
            outfile = open("big_out_%d" % (i // 1000000), "w")
        outfile.write(line)
    if outfile:
        outfile.close()
```

Note that I have simplified things a bit by using the index `i` from `enumerate` for all the counting rather than manually updating the `filenum` or `j` integers in your first code. That's unlikely to have any significant performance impact, but makes the code much nicer.